# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW on line 5, объясните пожалуйста в чем ошибка

Tags: php

```
<?php

$items = (
   'key1' => 'value1',
   'key2' => 'value2',
   );

 foreach($items as $key => $value){
   if((int)$value == 0){
     echo &key . '...';
   }
  }


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вообще пользуйтесь редактором, который подсвечивает ошибки в коде:

```
$items = [
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
];

foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
    if ((int) $value == 0) {
        echo $key . '...';
    }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.А не могли бы вы подсказать какой можно подобрать редактор, выделяющий ошибки?

Comment: @Gregor любой для php, хоть notepad++.

Comment: Мне нравится **Atom**

Comment: @Gregor если вам ответ помог. То отметьте его решением и можете поставить +.